# Tomcat not showing root cause of initialization failure

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, log4j

I'm trying to investigate some issues i have with my application, but i cannot get tomcat to show any meaningful error message.

When running Tomcat with my app deployed all i can see in logs that would indicate any problems are these messages:

```
ERROR org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  - Context    initialization failed
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/myApp]  - StandardWrapper.Throwable
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/myApp]  - Servlet /myApp threw load() exception
```

I cannot get it to show any stack trace or even exception name that would help solve my problem.

Is there any way to make Tomcat show more details about the root cause of failure?
I'm using tomcat 5.5.32, with root log4j logger set to DEBUG (and no other loggers defined)

Comment: Look into server log... `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs` -- the issue might be intializing code of your web app. Look into the code that executes on start up.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure it's initialization code of my web app. I just cannot find any information that would help me find the problem. I'd like to be able to configure tomcat so that it can show me what went wrong with the initialization

Comment: If you catch exceptions and do not properly propagate (rethrow) or log them, then they are lost. Is `Servlet /myApp threw load() exception` code you print out?

Answer (score 0):

Which logs are you looking at? Usually, `catalina.out` shows that you have an initialisation error, with the details in `localhost.${timestamp}.log`.